# How to reformat an auto formatted number using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Im fairly new to Javascript/JQuery. I wanted to autoformat a number while it was being inputted.
I used a Jquery plugin for the same -
`<script src="simple.money.format.js"></script>`
And calling it using 
`$('.money').simpleMoneyFormat();`

I want it be reformatted when I hit a button (Save) so that the value can be saved into the database.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Page load is *pretty different* from when some user clicks on a button.

Comment: Can you show us, what you have tried so far? Minimal viable example of code

Comment: @CertainPerformance Agreed. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler, the code will be called when the user hits the submit button, and before the data sent to the server

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function () {
    $('.money').simpleMoneyFormat();
});
```

Comment: Hi. I want the input to be formatted while the user is entering the values and want it to be reformatted back when the user hits on submit.  Right now after the Jquery function is being called, the value is not being saved to the database. I figured the reason is because the formatted number is being submitted. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what do you mean by formatting and reformatting back, I also don't know what does `simpleMoneyFormat` function, so if you can tell exactly what you want I may help you more, you can also see the other answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

See the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EliteSystemer/wv3sxo3j/

```
$('button').on("click", function() {  //Submit
  var m = $('.money').val();  //Get input value
  m = m.replace(/,/g, "");  //Remove commas
  $('.money').val(m);  //Update input value
  ...send to server
});
```